# Django Class Post has no object members

Tags: python, django

Class 'Post' has no 'objects' member?
Code Below--models file-->

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.utils import timezone
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User

 class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Code Below--views file--->

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Post

    def home(request):
       context = {
          'posts': Post.objects.all()
       }
       return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)

    def about(request):
       return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

---

please tell me this is an easy fix, I have no clue what could be wrong. using python3.7 for everything . It works on the server however in my code it says its an error. I don't like seeing errors, please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this an exception or is this a warning in your IDE?

Comment: So it works in the server but your editor shows error? Also, check the indentation of the str method, it seems a bit off

Comment: In my IDE- Visual Studio Code it is saying there is the current error. However in my terminal(MAC) where the server is running there are no errors.

Comment: @Dr.Errday you probably need to install some kind of Django plugin

Comment: Post doesn't appear to be what you think it is, perhaps it's getting stomped on. what does dir(Post) show?

Answer (score 0):

GUYS YOU WONT BELIVE THIS... it was a syntax error on import and it didnt flag it whatsoever. my pylint was also outdated